# Why I am getting VideoJs "i.tech_.playbackRate is not a function"?

Tags: video.js, vimeo-player

I am using videojs with the following package [videojs7-vimeo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs7-vimeo) to show vimeo videos to my customers. I hope this is the package to use, if there is a better one please let me know. My problem is if I click on the timeline of my videojs player it always throughs an error.

```
video.min.js:12 VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: i.tech_.playbackRate is not a function
at l.<anonymous> (video.min.js:19)
at HTMLDivElement.o.dispatcher.o.dispatcher (video.min.js:12)
at pe (video.min.js:12)
at trigger (video.min.js:12)
at e.<anonymous> (videojs-vimeo.min.js:7)
at videojs-vimeo.min.js:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at T (videojs-vimeo.min.js:1)
at a (videojs-vimeo.min.js:7)
```

Have no clue why this is. Maybe I am completely on the wrong track and it should be done different, but that was the only package I found.

Comment: We'll assume you saw this info:  https://github.com/videojs/videojs-vimeo/blob/master/index.html   If that doesn't solve it, then you'll need to post your javascript (which is most always necessary, when asking for help.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer solved it already! I am using https://github.com/vimeo/player.js now and everything is working fine!